# writing into a text file using C language

Tags: c, file-handling

I need to write all the "print" statements which are displayed in the command prompt into a text file. I know how to write into a text file by the usual way which is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  /* For exit() function */

int main() {
    char c[1000000];
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("program.txt", "w");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
    gets(c);
    fprintf(fptr, "%s", c);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

But from my knowledge we can't use it to write the print statements.
Please help!!!
_Thanks :)

Comment: You use `fprintf` then what make you think you cant ?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly is the problem ??

Comment: Scanning a sentence can't be done just by a single `%c`. You need to use something like `fgets()`.  I think the prob is since you are not scanning properly you don't see anything in the file

Comment: ... are you asking how to redirect stdout and/or stderr to a file, for your application only?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a file using printf by using `freopen()`

Use freopen() at the above of 1st printf()

ex: `freopen("filename.txt","w",stdout);`

Comment: Thank you all for the help it works now.. :)

Comment: If the answer helps you, accept the answer by clicking the green tick on left side @ThushiniUmanda